# MetaBox body is not showing (the callback function)

Tags: php, metabox

We're creating a plugin where, for example, it shows a metabox on all post types. To kick things off, I'm using the [Starter Kit](https://github.com/joshcummingsdesign/wp-plugin-starter).

```
<?php

namespace PLUGIN_NAME;

class Foo
{
  public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'admin_init', [ $this, 'wpd_add_meta_box' ] );
  }

function wpd_add_meta_box() {
        $screens = get_post_types();
        foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
            add_meta_box(
                'global-notice',
                __( 'Global Box ', 'global-box' ),
                'global_box_meta_box_callback',
                $screen,
                'advanced',
                'high'
            );
        }
    }

  function global_box_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
    echo "We're alive!"; // Never shows inside the metabox that is rendered.
  }

}
```

On a post page, I see the metabox but without the callback function.

Moving the code inside the `functions.php`, using `add_action( 'admin_init','wpd_add_meta_box')`, everything works fine.

How to render a metabox's content from a plugin within a class? Thanks.

Comment: That `global_box_meta_box_callback()` is a class method, so you need to use `[ $this, 'global_box_meta_box_callback' ]` when supplying the class method to `add_meta_box()`.

Comment: Thank you soo much! You could, if you like, add this as an answer so beginners like me to see?

Comment: I've just posted that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `global_box_meta_box_callback()` is a *class method* (i.e. a function inside a class) and not a globally defined function, so you need to use `[ $this, 'global_box_meta_box_callback' ]` (or `array( $this, 'global_box_meta_box_callback' )`) when supplying the class method to `add_meta_box()`:

```php
class Foo
{
    ...

    function wpd_add_meta_box() {
        $screens = get_post_types();
        foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
            add_meta_box(
                'global-notice',
                __( 'Global Box ', 'global-box' ),
                [ $this, 'global_box_meta_box_callback' ], // correct
//              'global_box_meta_box_callback',            // incorrect
                $screen,
                'advanced',
                'high'
            );
        }
    }

    function global_box_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

See the PHP [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for more details about using/supplying a callable/callback — in your case, we're using the object method call (see/find `// Type 3: Object method call` on that manual).